# Timeline keyframe not showing when changing to different transform rotation representation

Tags: animation, transforms

I created an animation, and created key frames when the rotation mode was set to Quaternion. Now I want to display the transform in easy to understand XYZ euler. The problem is, the rotation box does not indicate the keyframe exists in this mode, because the values are not in yellow.

[image]

Do I need to re-enter the key-frames again?
I would think I shouldn't have to since the XYZ is just a different representation of the Quaternion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quaternion, euler and axis angle rotations are stored as three different properties, the `rotation_mode` is used to determine which property is used for rotation.

Yes you will need to re-create the keyframes if you want to use a different rotation mode. You can choose the quaternion rotation mode, move to a keyframe and then change to euler and add a keyframe to the euler values as they will then match the values of the quaternion, then repeat for each keyframe of the rotation. If you have a lot of animation to do then a python script could be used to automate this.